# Why is the derived class' virtual override only called when it's not written as an iterator method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, polymorphism, .net-4.6.1

I'm adding unit tests for a class that uses Entity Framework. I've added test doubles based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/writing-test-doubles), and got a few tests running successfully. However, I reached a stumbling block when I began implementing a test targeting a section of code that relies on `DbSet<T>.RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T>)`. I added the following override to `TestDbSet<T>` (derived from `DbSet<T>`; from the link):

```
public override IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        Data.Remove(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

However, when I have an instance of `TestDbSet<T>` assigned to a `DbSet<T>` variable and try to call `RemoveRange`, it doesn't run the override that I wrote above -- it seems to be using the base class' implementation.

This baffled me for a bit. I confirmed that the instance was in fact a `TestDbSet<T>`, and of course it was, because the other method overrides were working. So I tried to think what was different about this method, and well, it's the only one iterator method (`yield return`), so I rewrote it without that:

```
public override IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    entities = entities.ToList();
    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        Data.Remove(item);
    }
    return entities;
}
```

...and suddenly it worked? Now when I call `RemoveRange` on the `DbSet<T>` (that's actually a `TestDbSet<T>`), it calls `TestDbSet<T>.RemoveRange` instead of `DbSet<T>.RemoveRange`.

I've tried switching it back and forth. I've confirmed that the `ToList()` alone doesn't fix it. Only avoiding `yield return` appears to fix it.

Can someone explain what's causing this? Does using an iterator method change the method's declaration or something? If so, how is that allowed/compatible with `override`?

Comment: How do you know override is not called?

Comment: @Evk do you imply that OP does not know that no visible code in functions with `yield return` execute before enumerating the sequence? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you do not enumerate the return value of `RemoveRange`. Iterator methods (the ones with `yield return`/`yield break`) are special - they are "lazy" and your code inside them is NOT executed right when you call the method, but only when the returned value is being enumerated. For example:

```
public static void Main() {
    Test();
}

static IEnumerable<int> Test() {
    Console.WriteLine("Got in");
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Returned 1");
}
```

This will print nothing to the console, because the return value of `Test` is never enumerated. This on the other hand:

```
public static void Main() {
    Test().ToList();
}

static IEnumerable<int> Test() {
    Console.WriteLine("Got in");
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Returned 1");
}
```

Will print both statements, because we are enumerating the result with `ToList()`.

This leads us to the fact you can't use iterator methods in your case - `RemoveRange` is not a valid candidate for that. Yes it returns `IEnumerable`, but the main purpose of this function is to remove entities, while the return value is kind of optional side effect and you can't expect the caller to always enumerate it (in most cases the return value will be completely ignored).